# Text floats to right instead of next to navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for my DofE expedition but am having some trouble making things work properly. The text that is currently floating on the right of the main container should be sat next to the navigation section but ma attempts to make it do so have been thus far unsuccessful. Any ideas on this?

If it helps, i'd like it to look something like this : [W3schools CSS Help Code](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_cols)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 background-color: #EEE;
}
#header {
 background-color: #66CCFF; 
 margin: auto;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
#container {
 background-color: white;
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
.main {
 font-family:  Helvetica;
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: auto;
 float: right;
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 clear: left;
 display: inline;
 /*margin: 1px;*/
}
#main2 {
 width: 799px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 width: 50%;
 display: inline;

 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 /*margin: 1px;*/
}
#nav{
 padding: 3px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
 color: red;
}

#nav li {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
 width: 25%;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    fl
}
#content {
 padding:10px;
}
#footer{
 clear: both;
 color: white;
 background-color: grey;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0.5px;
}
#footer-margin{
 margin: 5px;
}
img {
 /*margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;*/

 text-align:center;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 clear: right;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DofE:Expedition Aim</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container"><!--start container-->
 <div id = "header">
    <h1>DofE Expedition Aim</h1>
    </div>
  <div id = "content">
      <div id = "nav"><!-- start nav tag -->
          <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_1.html">Our Aim</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_2.html">How we acheived it</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_3.html">Extra info (tbd)</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div><!-- nav close tag -->
            <div class = "clearfix">
            <div class = "main">
            <p>This page shows what happened on out DofE expedition and the things that we did when not on expedition.</p>
            <p>This includes doing map work, fitness and orginising and running events localy.</p>
            <p>On the following pages, you can find the various evidence to show you what we did and how it benefited us. (or didn't)</p>
           
          </div><!-- "main" end tag -->
            <!--<div id = "main2">
            <p>This is a test of a second column that should float to the right of the other.</p>
            </div>-->
            </div>
           <!-- <div id = "img.1">
           <img src="logo.jpg" alt="DofE Logo goes here" height="100" width="73">
          </div>-->
     </div>
  <div id = "footer">
   <div id = "footer-margin">
   <p>Copyright &copy; Dom Brown 2017</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: set your `content` to display flex and remove the width of your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to play with the padding and such, but this will get the nav and main content side by side. Basically you had your clearfix container wrapping around just the nav, which was full width. Also I applied `float: left;` to both nav and main.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 background-color: #EEE;
}
#header {
 background-color: #66CCFF; 
 margin: auto;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
#container {
 background-color: white;
 width: 800px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
 font-family: Helvetica;
}
.main {
 font-family:  Helvetica;
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: auto;
 float: left;
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 display: inline;
 /*margin: 1px;*/
}
#main2 {
 width: 799px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 width: 50%;
 display: inline;

 background-color:#f2f2f2;
 /*margin: 1px;*/
}
#nav{
 padding: 3px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#nav li a:hover {
 color: red;
}

#nav li {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 background-color: #dddddd;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content {
 padding:10px;
}
#footer{
 clear: both;
 color: white;
 background-color: grey;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0.5px;
}
#footer-margin{
 margin: 5px;
}
img {
 /*margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;*/

 text-align:center;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 clear: right;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DofE:Expedition Aim</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id = "container"><!--start container-->
 <div id = "header">
    <h1>DofE Expedition Aim</h1>
    </div>
  <div id = "content" class="clearfix">
      <div id = "nav"><!-- start nav tag -->
          <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_1.html">Our Aim</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_2.html">How we acheived it</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_3.html">Extra info (tbd)</a></li>
          </ul>
         </div><!-- nav close tag -->
            <div class = "main">
            <p>This page shows what happened on out DofE expedition and the things that we did when not on expedition.</p>
            <p>This includes doing map work, fitness and orginising and running events localy.</p>
            <p>On the following pages, you can find the various evidence to show you what we did and how it benefited us. (or didn't)</p>
           
          </div><!-- "main" end tag -->
            <!--<div id = "main2">
            <p>This is a test of a second column that should float to the right of the other.</p>
            </div>-->
           <!-- <div id = "img.1">
           <img src="logo.jpg" alt="DofE Logo goes here" height="100" width="73">
          </div>-->
     </div>
  <div id = "footer">
   <div id = "footer-margin">
   <p>Copyright &copy; Dom Brown 2017</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can i ask what the clearfix actually does? I added it in after looking over some other websites that said it was a good idea. I hoped it would help before you fixed it...

Comment: Yeah sure. Basically a container of floated items, ignores the floated items when calculating its height by default, to get around this we apply a clearfix to the container, this 'clears' the floats giving the container the desired height. If you don't apply a clearfix your footer wouldn't be positioned at the bottom of the main container. If you want to read in to this more see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your css like this

```
#nav{
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```